# Text data source supports only a single column, and you have 8 columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is the error I got when I tried to save a data frame to text:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Text data source supports only a single column, and you have 8 columns
```

This is the code:

```
df.write.text("/tmp/wt")
```

What I m doing wrong?

Comment: spark 1.6.3 and scala 2.10.5

Comment: should I need `com.databricks.spark.csv` to done this job, if so, I can't use this library, I have to find other alternative

Comment: .csv is supported from spark 2.0 onwards only. so yes you would need databricks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Spark 1.6, the easiest solution is to use databricks' library and write:

```
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("pathToFile.csv")
```

If you do not want to use it, you can simply convert the rows of your dataframe into csv lines like this:

```
df.rdd
  .map(_.toSeq.map(_+"").reduce(_+";"+_))
  .saveAsTextFile("pathToFile.csv")
```

Note that if your fields can contain separators or quotes, you will have to add enclosing quotes and escape existing quotes, things that the library would do for you transparently.

Comment: Is it possible to specify the output mode as SaveMode by coding it like so?
df.rdd
  .map(_.toSeq.map(_+"").reduce(_+";"+_))
  .saveAsTextFile("pathToFile.csv")