# Unable to add headers to the text file while saving the file as saveAsTextFile

Tags: scala, pyspark, azure-databricks

I referred to link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668201/text-data-source-supports-only-a-single-column-and-you-have-8-columns](https://stackoverflow.com) for the solution provided for error "text data source supports only a single column".

Applied the solution

```
df.rdd.map(.toSeq.map(+"").reduce(+"|"+)).saveAsTextFile("adlspath/filename")
```

Output looks good but unable to add headers to the file . I tried adding option("header",true) it does not work. Is there any other way I can add heareds while saving as text file.Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

**I reproduce the same in my environment by adding headers to the text file. I got this output.**

For the demo, This is my sample Dataframe without a header:

[image]

Creating separate columns, I am using `split(",")`. this command split the lines of the DataFrame with `","`.

```
d1 = data.rdd.map(lambda x: x[0].split(",")).toDF()
```

Adding a header to the data frame using the below code.

```
header1 = ["h1", "h2", "h3"]
data1 = d1.toDF(*header)
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Updated:**

If you want to write the data into text use delta format use below code.

```
data.write.format("delta").option("header","true").mode('overwrite').save("/mnt/samp/ds")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You Sai for your inputs ! I tried to write the data (dataframe) using format('text') as suggest above but I got error saying Incompatible format .You must use format('delta') .

Comment: yes, you correct , if you have `Text` format source it supports only a single column. if you using delta format it work's perfectly fine : )

Comment: @SrinivasM, above issue resolved ?

Comment: Hi Sai , Yes Issue resolved . for column headers separate rdd created and did union with data rdd to generate records into sequence of single column . and then passed result to saveAsTextFile (adls_path). then used part files to move them to .txt file .And Thank You for your suggestions as well. Thanks Srinivas